# Name resolving error when implementing static method from a trait

Tags: methods, static, rust, traits

Here is slightly modified example from tutorial:

```
use std::f64::consts::PI;

trait Awesome {
  fn how_awesome() -> int;
}

struct Circle { radius: f64 }
impl Circle {
    fn area(&self) -> f64 { self.radius * self.radius * PI }
    fn new(area: f64) -> Circle { Circle { radius: (area / PI).sqrt() } }
}


impl Awesome for Circle {
    fn how_awesome() -> int { 5 }
}

fn main() {
    let c = Circle::new(42.5); // fine
    let c2 = Circle::how_awesome(); // error: unresolved name `Circle::how_awesome`.
}
```

It can get even stranger than this:

```
struct Point {
  x: f64,
  y: f64
}

impl Awesome for Point {
    fn how_awesome() -> int { 3 }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Point::how_awesome();
}
```

results in

```
ERROR:rustc::middle::resolve: !!! (resolving module in lexical scope) module wasn't actually a module!
type.rs:41:11: 41:25 error: unresolved name
type.rs:41   let p = Point::how_awesome();
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
type.rs:41:11: 41:25 error: use of undeclared module `Point`
type.rs:41   let p = Point::how_awesome();
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
ERROR:rustc::middle::resolve: !!! (resolving module in lexical scope) module wasn't actually a module!
type.rs:41:11: 41:25 error: unresolved name `Point::how_awesome`.
type.rs:41   let p = Point::how_awesome(); 
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm using fairly fresh nightly:

```
rustc 0.11.0-pre-nightly (db5ca23 2014-05-14 01:06:24 -0700)
host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Searching for this issue reviles absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, all methods are scoped with their trait, including static methods. Until [uniform function call syntax (UFCS)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/4) is implemented, you need to call them on the trait themselves:

```
let p = Awesome::how_awesome();
```

However, the compiler needs some way to work out exactly which implementation of that trait should be used, i.e. some way to infer the type on the RHS of the `for` to find the specific `impl`. As written, the `how_awesome` method doesn't mention this `Self` type at all, so there is no way for the compiler to just infer it (like with [the `default` method of the `Default` trait](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/core/default/trait.Default.html), which can be used like `let x: Type = Default::default();`).

There should be a way to specify it manually, but we currently don't have one. This is again something covered by the UFCS RFC, for the moment the only way around it is a hack like:

```
struct Point {
  x: f64,
  y: f64
}

trait Awesome {
    fn how_awesome(_ignored: Option<Self>) -> int;
}

impl Awesome for Point {
    fn how_awesome(_ignore: Option<Point>) -> int { 0 }
}

fn main() {
    let p = Awesome::how_awesome(None::<Point>);
}
```

---

I filed [#14225](https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/14225) about the ugly error for `Point::how_awesome`.